# JavaMail : FolderClosedException coming frequently

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using java mail to connect with gmail and I'm keeping one store for the all actions. (Store is set to static.).
And the IMAPFolder instances are attached with imap listeners. So the folders are kept always open. (Folder close is not called any time) But while running after few minutes I'm getting FolderClosedException. After that exception, though the folder can be reopened but the idle() command cannot be issued again, which will result in NullPointerException.

Is there any wrong with keeping folders open always?

Thanks in advance.

===================================================================

[Edit]
Here I'm pasting the actual code i'm doing POC with. The NullPointerException comes when I check .isConnected() after reconnecting the store. Below is the run method of Thread which sends idle() command to the store.

```
public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Checking connectivity...");

                if (store.isConnected()) {
                    store.idle();
                    System.out.println("IDLE send...");
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("Tring to connect...");

                    //Trying to reconnect to the store.
                    store.connect();
                    System.out.println("Previous store connected again");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException...");
            } catch (StoreClosedException ex) {
                System.out.println("StoreClosedException...");
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                System.out.println("MessagingException...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.waitIfIdle(IMAPStore.java:1881)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.getStoreProtocol(IMAPStore.java:946)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.isConnected(IMAPStore.java:1347)
at pocworks.POCWorks1$IDLEThread.run(POCWorks1.java:125)
```

Comment: Anybody with any idea? Really appreciate any suggestion as this is very urgent. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, mail servers don't like you to keep connections open when you're not using them.  Typical IMAP servers will give you 30 minutes before they time out an unused connection; Gmail may be more aggressive.

Comment: Thank you very much Shannon. When such time out occurs, what should the mail client do? I tried to reconnect the same store but it throws NullPointException when issuing idle() command again. And all IMAPFolders throws FolderClosedException repeatedly, because of their listeners running. <br/> Should I have to recreate a new store and get IMAPFolders from that store from the scratch?

Comment: You can reconnect the Store, but you'll also need to reopen the Folder.  Can you show me the stack trace for the NullPointerException you're getting?

Comment: Thanks Bill for the advice. I have edited the original post with code snippet and the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace.  It looks like there's a bug that causes the NullPointerException if the connection is dropped at the wrong time while waiting for the IDLE response.

Comment: Until we get a fix in next release, can you please suggest a workaround?

Comment: Catch the NullPointerException and treat it just like a FolderClosedException.